# Is android using a different java lib?

Tags: java, android, frameworks

When I read the framework code of android, I find that the code invoke a method named setInt$ in the class FileDescriptor. However, when I read java api, I didn't find the method.
Here is the code of android framework (located at base\core\java\android\app\ActivityThread.java)

```java
private FileDescriptor openDeprecatedDataPath(String path, int mode) throws ErrnoException {
            final Uri uri = ContentResolver.translateDeprecatedDataPath(path);
            Log.v(TAG, "Redirecting " + path + " to " + uri);

            final ContentResolver cr = currentActivityThread().getApplication()
                    .getContentResolver();
            try {
                final FileDescriptor fd = new FileDescriptor();
                fd.setInt$(cr.openFileDescriptor(uri,
                        FileUtils.translateModePosixToString(mode)).detachFd());
                return fd;
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                throw new ErrnoException(e.getMessage(), OsConstants.EACCES);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                throw new ErrnoException(e.getMessage(), OsConstants.ENOENT);
            }
        }
```

I want to know if android framework is using a different java lib compared with the one that we normally used. If it does, then how can I find the java lib it uses.

Comment: *Every* Java version has a different library. That’s why you should stick to the `public` (and for extensible types, `protected`) API. Even a minor update may have different `private` members in its classes.